# Using ANTLR generated to parse input file and display correctness

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

So I have a grammar and generated a Parser using ANTLR4. The generated parser works fine on the terminal. Now here is my problem, I need to make a java program that will accept the name of a file as an argument and go through each line of the file and check if the syntax/meaning is correct. If it is it will output correct and if not it will either output false or maybe the errors. ANTLR has generated the java lexer file and java parser file. 
I have this so far:

```
CharStream characterStream = CharStreams.fromFileName("input.txt");
ANTLRLexer lexer = new ANTLRLexer(charstream);
ANTLRParser parser = new ANTLRParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
```

Like I am not even sure what the variable parser does. How do I proceed from here to check each line.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: My bad, it was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your grammar contains a rule `lines` that goes through all lines (note that you'll want to use `EOF` to make sure that it does go through all lines), all you need to do is to invoke it:

```
parser.lines();
```